# Configure C1861 for SIP to FXS port

Tags: voip, sip, cisco-voip

I found a C1861 ISR router and I would like to play with it a learn some telephony.

I signed up for a VOIP service so I have SIP credentials. Is there a simple walkthrough anywhere to set up the SIP so I can plug a POTS phone in the FXS port and be able to place and receive calls?  Also anything for configuring an IP phone in a regular switch port?

Thank you any help you may provide.

Comment: Do you have the correct license for VoIP on your router?

Comment: Does this show license info?

Processor board ID FTX16268279
MPC8358 CPU Rev: Part Number 0x804A, Revision ID 0x21
12 User Licenses
10 FastEthernet interfaces
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
4 Voice FXO interfaces
4 Voice FXS interfaces
1 Voice MoH interface
128K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
2006928K bytes of ATA CompactFlash (Read/Write)


License Info:

License UDI:

-------------------------------------------------
Device#   PID                   SN
-------------------------------------------------
*0        C1861E-SRST-F/K9      FTX16268279